# AngularJS, RequireJS, Karma - Test File not loading

Tags: angularjs, requirejs, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I'm currently attempting to run tests using Karma, however I can't seem to load the Test file...

this is my file structure:

```
app
    controllers
        ..
    directives
    ..
..
test
    customersControllerTest.js
karma.conf.js
test-main.js
..
```

this is my current karma.conf.js file:

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: '',

    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['jasmine', 'requirejs'],

    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
        {pattern: './scripts/jquery.js', included: true},
        {pattern: './scripts/angular.js', included: true},
        {pattern: './scripts/angular-mocks.js', included: true},
        'test-main.js',
        {pattern: './test/*.js', included: false},
        {pattern: './app/**/*.js', included: false},
    ],

    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [
      '**/*.css',
      '**/bootstrap.js',
      '**/routes.js',
      '**/conf.js',
      '**/app.js'
    ],

    // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
    // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
    preprocessors: {
    },

    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
    // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
    reporters: ['progress'],

    // web server port
    port: 9876,

    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,

    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_DEBUG,

    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: true,

    // start these browsers
    // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
    browsers: ['PhantomJS', 'Chrome', 'Firefox'],

    plugins: [
        'karma-*',
    ],

    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

and my test-main.js file:

```
var testPaths = {
    'customersControllersTest': '../test/customersControllersTest'
},  tests = Object.keys(window.__karma__.files).filter(function(file) {
    return (/(spec|Test)\.js$/i.test(file));
}).map(function(test) {
    var returnVal = false;
    Object.keys(testPaths).map(function(path){
        if(testPaths[path] === test.replace('/base', '..').replace('.js', '')) {
            returnVal = path;
        }
    });
    return returnVal;
});

require.config({
    // Karma serves files under /base, which is the basePath from your config file
    baseUrl: '/base/app',
    paths: {
        'jquery': '../scripts/jquery',
        'angular': '../scripts/angular',
        'angularMocks': '../scripts/angular-mocks',

        // Modules
        'servicesModule': './services/module',
        'directivesModule': './directives/module',
        'controllersModule': './controllers/module',

        // Controllers
        'testController': './controllers/testController',
        'ordersController': './controllers/ordersController',
        'allordersController': './controllers/allordersController',
        'customersController': './controllers/customersController',

        // Directives
        'barChart': './directives/barsChartDirective',
        'blueBarChart': './directives/blueBarsChartDirective',

        // Services
        'testService': './services/testService',
        'routeResolver': './services/routeResolver',
        'customersFactory': './services/customersFactory',

        // Tests
        'customersControllersTest': '../test/customersControllersTest'
    },
    // angular does not support AMD out of the box, put it in a shim
    shim: {
        'angular': {
            deps: ['jquery'],
            exports: 'angular'
        },
        'angularRoute': ['angular'],
        'angularAnimate': ['angular'],
        'angularMocks': ['angular']
    },
    // dynamically load all test files
    deps: tests,
    // we have to kickoff jasmine, as it is asynchronous
    callback: window.__karma__.start()
});
```

and my customersControllersTest.js:

```
define('customersControllersTest', [], function() {
    describe('test', function() {
        console.log(this);
        it('test1', function() {
            expect('this').toEqual('this');
        });
        console.log(this);
    });
});
```

By checking in Chrome's devtools, it gives an Error:

[image: Error]

but when I open it:

[image: File loaded]

This however might be completely unrelated, since I keep getting the following:

[image]

which, asides for saying it found no test, is yelling Error...

Any ideas on how I can tackle this?

Comment: what is the purpose of the `map()` that comes after `filter()` when test-main.js builds the list of `tests`?

Comment: the inner-most map could probably be a forEach, since I'm just assigning the value to a variable so that I call the requireJS module instead of the file itself (so require does it's magic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem is the line:

```
callback: window.__karma__.start()
```

This calls `start` right away instead of passing it as `callback`. This line should have been

```
callback: window.__karma__.start
```

See [karma-requirejs README](https://github.com/kjbekkelund/karma-requirejs).

Comment: this actually fixed it... I'll be telling the original source of the error too (copy-pasted the structure from a website) thanks for it :)